# On a property for normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

I came upon the following specific property for a normed space $X$, and I am looking for a characterization of the normed spaces where it holds true:

If a sequence $x_n$ in $X$ satisfies $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}(\|x_n+y\|-\|x_n\|)=\|y\|$ for all $y\in X$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$.

This is not true in $l_1$; take $x_n=e_n$, the unit vector basis. The same counterexample doesn't seem to work in $c_0$, $l_\infty$, and $l_p$ for $p\neq 1$. Is this actually true in these spaces, or is this property, in fact, never satisfied?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but in a Hilbert space the condition you give is *close* to the statement that $x_n\rightharpoonup 0$ weakly. Now, in any uniformly convex Banach space, weak convergence + convergence in norms implies strong convergence. I don't think this is what you're looking for, but I hope this helps.

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give you a full, but not satisfactory, general characterization of your property, and then a much nicer characterization of your property among separable spaces.

First we say that a sequence $(x_n)$ is $L$-orthogonal if $\|x_n + x \| \rightarrow 1 + \|x\|$ for every $x \in X$; and we say that an element $x^{**} \in X^{**}$ is $L$-orthogonal if $\|x^{**} + x\| = \|x^*\| + \|x\|$ for every $x \in X$.

**Proposition.** A Banach space $X$ has your property iff it does not contain an $L$-orthogonal sequence.

*Proof.* First note that any $L$-orthogonal sequence $(x_n)$ satisfies the assumption of your property, but $\|x_n\| \rightarrow 1$, so spaces containing $L$-orthogonal sequences cannot have your property.
On the other hand suppose that $X$ does not satisfy your property, witnessed by a sequence $(x_n)$. As $(x_n)$ is bounded and not converging to zero, there is $c > 0$ and a subsequence $(y_n)$ of the sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\|y_n\| \rightarrow c$. But then $z_n = c^{-1} y_n$ forms an $L$-orthogonal sequence. QED

$L$-orthogonal sequences have been studied, so you can find something about your spaces. Let me mention some known results (for them and more see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.05535.pdf) by Avilés et. al. and references therein).

1. A Banach space $X$ contains $\ell_1$ iff there is an $L$-orthogonal element in $X^{**}$.
2. If $X$ is a Banach space of density $\leq \mathfrak{p}$ (the pseudointersection number) and $X$ contains $L$-orthogonal sequence, then there is an $L$-orthogonal element in $X^{**}$. This particulary holds for separable $X$.
3. If $X$ is separable Banach space and $X^{**}$ contains $L$-orthogonal element, then $X$ contains an $L$-orthogonal sequence.

In particular, combining the results above, you get:

**Proposition.** Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. Then $X$ has your property iff $X$ does not contain $\ell_1$.

The proposition above gives you that all the spaces $c_0,\ell_p$, $1 < p < \infty$ have your property.

Comment: Thanks! In the first line of the proof, it should be "any $L$-orthogonal sequence *does not* satisfy...."